# C# Web App Question

Tags: c#

I want to show the contents of a folder in my C# web app. How do I get this done? I know how too in windows apps, but Im working on a web app here.

Thanks

Updated:

Sorry guys, I have two servers, A & B. A has the web app and on server B, I want have the file folder that I want to place files in, excel files, etc. My web app is going to process the files and I want the ability to show within the app what files are in the folder on server B. Does this help?

Comment: A server side folder or a client side folder?

Comment: A folder on the machine the web browser is running on or a folder on the server machine?  Since the C# part will run on the server, it won't have access to the local machine.

Comment: need more info here. are you trying to show a folder on the client machine or on the server? It's straight-forward if the folder is on the server, but you'll need an ActiveX control if you want to display a folder on the client.

Comment: @Oded, sounds like a server folder in the current web-site root.

Comment: @Filip - possibly, but I don't get that from the question. The fact that this isn't possible client side doesn't mean that the OP didn't mean just that ;)

Comment: True that. :) However, it is "Possible" to do on the client side, but that depends on what kind of webapp it is. You can (afaik) use Flash or an Applet to get a file list. And iirc you could do it with Silverlight / XBAP too.

Comment: FYI, this question title is too generic. Something like "Showing folder contents in C# web app" would help people make informed judgments about your post.

Comment: OK, I have a web app that will be placed onto a server (server A) and I have a file folder on another server that within the webpage I want to be able to show the contents of the file folder (server B). Does this help any ?

Comment: @gabrielVa, I've updated my answer. Does it reflect on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assuming that you want to list content of a web-folder on the server**

Since I don't know if you are doing this in ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WebForms I will just use `Response.Write` to print it out on the page.

What you need to do is pretty much like you do in a windows app, you use `DirectoryInfo` to get a file list and then you can get the file info out of that.

Remember that the User running the web-server / web-app need to have permissions to read and list files from that folder.

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebapp\folder1").GetFiles();
foreach(var file in files)
{
    Response.WriteLine(file.FullName);
}
```

**Listing files on the clients machine inside your webb-application**

Using Javascript to do this is Impossible, since Javascript lives inside the browser and has no way of contacting content outside of the scope of the web-browser. There are however alternatives to this, you can use Java Applets, Flash, Silverlight, XBAP or ActiveX to read files from the client machine. However this must then be allowed by the user and the user needs to have the specific runtimes.

And you most certainly cannot read files on the client machine using C# because your Web Application ( if it is not XBAP ) lives and runs on the server machine and does not have a connection to the client computer besides the stateless communication over HTTP.

**Reading files from another server**

If the servers are on the same network and assuming both are running windows you could just mount a network volume and read the files as show in the first section of my post. However if they are not, you can either use FTP with C# to access a file list, [check out FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) for that.

Or another option is to put a WebService on the other server and have it return file lists to you. You can read about begining Windows Communication Foundation implementations over at [this blog](http://www.programminghelp.com/programming/dotnet/wcf-creating-and-implementing-a-service-in-c/).

Comment: how do you know OP wants to display a server-side folder? Since OP references doing it in a Windows app I'd assume that he's trying to show a client-side folder, which would require an ActiveX control.

Comment: @Brian, it's just a hunch. Yes it would require another way of doing it, see my comment to @Oded. I can't however understand why it deserves a down-vote since it answers one of the aspects.

Comment: @Biran, now the answer should be bullet-proof. :)